# How to install Google VR SDK in Android Studio

Tags: sdk, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I am getting into virtual reality apps and I would like to build my own VR player app. How can I download Google VR SDK and install it in Android Studio, so I can start playing around with its features. Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are listed here (at the time of writing):  https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started

Its maybe a little unclear, but you just need to download the Google VR SDK for Android and put it wherever you want on your local machine.

Once you have it there, you can open studio and use 'Open an existing Android Studio project', then select the directory and choose one of the sample projects and you should be up and running.

If you want to build it into your own project then you need to add in the dependency to your project gradle build file. I would strongly suggest you check the link again if you are having problems, as this is relatively new and the instructions may change over time and a blog or other guides may be out of date.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I already downloaded the SDK, an I already opened a new Android Studio project. I am having trouble when trying to add the dependency  to the project gradle build file. I use compile and include for the different features of the VR SDK but after Sync the Android Studio does not create the new gradles. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Thats probably worth a different specific question - I would add in the gradle file code if possible and any error messages in the question also